# Injecting Django attributes into Java script

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to add the title of my post to a javascript but I am doing wrong it is not showing correctly.

My objective is the show the title and the link of the Django page to the Facebook sharing button.

The name of the app is score

Here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    design = models.ImageField(
        blank=False, null=True, upload_to=upload_design_to)
```

Here is the post-details.html

```
        <!-- Share Buttons TODO -->
            <div class="icons">
              <ul>
                <a target="_blank" class="facebook-btn" href="https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}"><li class="facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li></a>
                <a target="_blank" class="twitter-btn" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}"><li class="twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li></a>
                <a target="_blank" class="linkedin-btn" href="#"><li class="linkedin"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></li></a>
              </ul>
            </div>
        <!-- Share Buttons  -->
```

Here is the script

```
    function init() {
        let postUrl = encodeURI(document.location.href);
        let postTitle = score=> score['title'];
        console.log(postTitle);
    }
    init();
```

My question: how to get the console to show the name of the {{ object.title }}, currently it is showing `score=> score['title']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the script is within a template file, you can query your database in the view that corresponds to your post-details.html file. Then pass the value to your template through the views context variable. Finally, assign to a JS variable:

```
const postTitle = “{{ your_context_variable_name.title }}”;
```

Comment: This is correct but it needed to add `let postTitle = "{{ object.title }}";`

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to use your template to write the value as a javascript global variable, which your script refers to.

Your template could have a fragment like this

```
{% block js %}
    <script> 
        var job_id = {{ job_id }};
    </script>
    <script src="{% static 'cin7_sync/js/myscript.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

and the script refers to the var job_id